# PHP Authorization header not found

Tags: php, apache, cgi, basic-authentication, fastcgi

I am working on the codeigniter basic authentication by using Rest_controller. Currently i having the issue on getting anyone of them in the list below from my `$_SERVER` array object.

- `PHP_AUTH_USER`
- `PHP_AUTH_PW`
- `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`
- `HTTP_AUTHENTICATION`

Based on my research, the problem is because of the Server API on my server. The Server API of this server is using CGI/FastCGI.

I even tried add all these to my `.htaccess` but none of them is working for me.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
CGIPassAuth on
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Authorization"
```

The array below is what is get from my `$_SERVER` when i try call my api from the postman.
[image: MY API CALL BY USING POSTMAN IMAGE]

```
     array(52) {
    ["PATH"]=>
    string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
    ["TZ"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
    ["REDIRECT_HANDLER"]=>
    string(28) "application/x-httpd-ea-php56"
    ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
    string(3) "200"
    ["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
    string(27) "Wgu-pu3SJZU707d76yB41AAAAAE"
    ["SCRIPT_URL"]=>
    string(24) "/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["SCRIPT_URI"]=>
    string(49) "https://www.river-app.com/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["HTTPS"]=>
    string(2) "on"
    ["SSL_TLS_SNI"]=>
    string(17) "www.river-app.com"
    ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
    string(17) "www.river-app.com"
    ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=>
    string(8) "no-cache"
    ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]=>
    string(51) "chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop"
    ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
    string(121) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
    ["HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN"]=>
    string(36) "12be9c43-7d88-3244-b407-ff0a160434ce"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
    string(3) "*/*"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
    string(17) "gzip, deflate, br"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
    string(38) "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4"
    ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
    string(43) "ci_session=ne4ip07sqkrree86dgmjfackgbn4f4bk"
    ["HTTP_X_HTTPS"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
    string(6) "Apache"
    ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
    string(17) "www.river-app.com"
    ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
    string(14) "67.225.226.183"
    ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
    string(3) "443"
    ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
    string(15) "118.200.235.133"
    ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
    string(26) "/home/riverapp/public_html"
    ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=>
    string(5) "https"
    ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=>
    string(8) "/cgi-sys"
    ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
    string(26) "/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/"
    ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
    string(23) "webmaster@river-app.com"
    ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
    string(36) "/home/riverapp/public_html/index.php"
    ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
    string(5) "60875"
    ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
    string(24) "/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
    string(7) "CGI/1.1"
    ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
    string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
    string(4) "POST"
    ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
    string(24) "/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
    string(10) "/index.php"
    ["PATH_INFO"]=>
    string(14) "/test_api/test"
    ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
    string(40) "/home/riverapp/public_html/test_api/test"
    ["ORIG_PATH_INFO"]=>
    string(24) "/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
    string(17) "/cgi-sys/ea-php56"
    ["ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
    string(34) "/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56"
    ["ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
    string(50) "/home/riverapp/public_html/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["PHP_SELF"]=>
    string(24) "/index.php/test_api/test"
    ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
    float(1510719398.04)
    ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
    int(1510719398)
    ["argv"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["argc"]=>
    int(0)
    }
```

What could be the thing causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to top of your controller

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: sorry, kuma. my question is about the authorization header not found in my $_server array when i try call the api. Not about the convert the array or json object